# More Than 1 External CSS Stylesheet Per Link Tag

Tags: html, css

Say I have an HTML page linking to an external stylesheet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <title>Whatever Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    // body goes here

    </body>
</html>
```

Now, say I want to add another stylesheet (or 2 or 3 or 500). The usual way to do this is to have more than 1 `<link>` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="old.css" />
...
```

Or maybe @importing, but I've never really done that personally. However, is there a way to have more than 1 stylesheet for a single `<link>` tag, probably in the `href` part? Perhaps something like this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css; new.css; old.css" />
```

More generally, is there a way to do this with other attributes of other tags, like with `<script>` tags or `<a>` tags (that last one would be weird)?

By the way, in case you were wondering, the syntax I used was for HTML5, but I'm sure it would be the same with HTML 4.01.

Comment: If you intended to use HTML5 then you did it wrong. `link` tags should not be closed like this `... />`. Remove the slash. The same is for all tags that don't have enclosing tag, e.g. `<br>`, `<input...>` etc.

Comment: @matewka — HTML 5 allows the `/` characters at the end of tags defined as empty. It's a waste of bytes, but calms those addicted to XML (or who use HTML-unaware syntax highlighters).

Comment: You can do it both ways. Neither way is wrong except in XHTML, where my way would be wrong. I think with the W3C HTML validator the way I did it doesn't validate correctly, & many people see that as "official", but who really cares?

Comment: I agree with Quentin, though, that if you're worried about a few bits, you shouldn't do it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot specify multiple locations in the `href` attribute.  Per the spec, each `<link>` represents a document that is connected to your html.  So by design it would be only one document.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.3